# Oracle Advanced Queuing

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm  working on one of the project where Oracle AQ has been implemented.
Here, we have couple of Queue tables, I'm trying to find out how data is inserted into these tables. I did looked into all available triggers but don't see any trigger inserting data into that queue table.

I tried to look with all_dependencies for specific queue table with below query, but not luck.

```
select * from DBA_DEPENDENCIES DD
where DD.referenced_owner = 'XYZ' and
      DD.name like 'XYZ' and
      DD.type like 'TABLE'
```

Can anyone help me know, how to find out data being inserted into Queue Tables.

Comment: [Advanced Queuing Operations Using PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/aq_opers.htm#ADQUE1000)

Answer (score 1):

ORACLE AQ table's would get populated through DBMS_AQ package not through any DML's.
A call to procedure DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE would populate a msg/record into the queue table and call to procedure DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE would read a msg/record from the queue table.

So do a source search for DBMS_AQ to know how the data is getting populated into this table.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching all database source using following statement. There may a scheduled job or another plsql procedure triggered by shell scrips etc.

```
select * from dba_source where text like '%XYZ%';
```